# Strange behaviour mock’s side_effect function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have this piece of code:

```
import postie

def send_mail(self, outbox):
    try:
        postie.postmail(self.dbname, outbox)
    except postie.EmailDeliveryException:
        self.logger.error('Fail to send mail’)
        return False
    return True
```

And I want to test the case a postie.EmailDeliveryException is raised.
So I mock out postie.postmail and put the exception as aside effect of its call:

```
import postie

@patch('postie.postmail')
def test_send_mail_False(self, postie_stub):
    ''' Mail send failed '''
    postie_stub.return_value = None
    postie_stub.side_effect = postie.EmailDeliveryException
    op = OutboxProcessor('db name', None, None)
    self.assertFalse(op.send_mail(Outbox()))
```

The above results in:

```
test_send_mail_False (test_outbox_processor.OutboxProcessorTestCase)
Mail send failed ... No handlers could be found for logger "outbox"
ok
```

Now I want to mock out the logger and check that the error function is also called in case of ‘EmailDeliveryException’. So I go:

```
@patch('postie.postmail')
@patch.object(Logger, 'error')
def test_send_mail_False(self, postie_stub, logger_stub):
    ''' Mail sending failed '''
    postie_stub.return_value = None
    postie_stub.side_effect = postie.EmailDeliveryException
    logger_stub.return_value = None

    op = OutboxProcessor('db name', None, None)
    self.assertFalse(op.send_mail(Outbox(), None))
    logger_stub.assert_called()
```

The result will be:

```
FAIL: test_send_mail_False (test_outbox_processor.OutboxProcessorTestCase)
Mail sending failed
AssertionError: True is not false
```

So it looks like the assertFalse does no longer succeed, (probably the exception is no longer raised). Anyone has any idea if anything interferes with my side_effect here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect order of patch decorators (or stub arguments). Here's an explanation from [mock docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> When you nest patch decorators the mocks are passed in to the
>   decorated function in the same order they applied (the normal python
>   order that decorators are applied). This means from the bottom up...

So it should be:

```
@patch.object(Logger, 'error')
@patch('postie.postmail')
def test_send_mail_False(self, postie_stub, logger_stub):
    ''' Mail sending failed '''
```

Comment: Jesus! I missed this one! Thanks a ton!